# Outlook: How to add shortcut for room calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I make heavy use of the shortcuts section/tab/mode/whatever of the Folder Pane, as it enables me to access all my items (mailboxes, calendars, tasks) from a single section rather than constantly switching between sections.

In the past, people used to share calendars by creating a calendar in a Public Folder, and it was possible to add a shortcut for those calendars by right-clicking on a shortcut group, clicking new shortcut and then browsing Public Folders to find them.

Lately, more and more room calendars are being shared using some other mechanism where they don't show up in any Public Folder but you can find them by searching in the directory. For example File -> Open -> Other User's Folders -> Name, and then search for the room/organization calendar you want.

Is there any way to create a shortcut for these types of calendars?
I'm currently using outlook 2016, but couldn't figure this out in 2010 either.